# How to change the color of the UISearchBar Icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I don't know how to modify the original `searchIcon`'s color.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a custom image of a white search icon, as the search bar will not modify your supplied image. To set a custom image, use this method. ([Link to documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state:))

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage
forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon
           state:(UIControlState)state;
```

Example Code:

```
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchIcon"]
   forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
              state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In Swift:

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "SearchIcon"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Comment: I've never had to use SearchBar so i don't have example ready to post, but https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state: maybe this can help you

Comment: Maybe this method should be better: 

`- (UIImage *)imageForSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon
                             state:(UIControlState)state`

Comment: exemple :   [searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchIconSearch"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: This is a bit late, but if people need to know, the icon is 13x13px. The glass icon can be found [here](ic8.link/7695). use 13x13 for 1x, 26x26 for 2x, and 39x39 for 3x. Just thought I would throw that out there

Comment: Minebomer   That seems a bit small.   24x24 @1x  etc.  is smaller than default on the sim.

Comment: Im pretty sure the image gets resized so as long as the image is large enough it will scale down.

Comment: Simple things must be simple. The question was about changing color, not changing image.

Comment: With iOS 13 and later you can use the system search image with SF Symbols, so you don't have to provide your own icon.

Answer (score 64):

The searchIcon is located in the leftView of the searchTextField. Since this is accessible we can easily set the tintColor for the view. The tintColor is also used for the searchIcon.

So in your code you can change the search icon to white with the following code:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: For those who only need to change the color, this solution is perfect! Thanks @Milander

Comment: Works perfectly and feels less "tricky" than others solutions that may not work in future releases of iOS, but beware this attribute is not available earlier to iOS 13.

Comment: perfect. why so hard to find the proper and easy solution.

Comment: this worked for me. Simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 43):

Best solution I found was here
[Changing the color of the icons in a UItextField inside a UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699859/changing-the-color-of-the-icons-in-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uisearchbar)

(This solution uses the original UISearchBar's icon, no need to supply your own graphical asset)

Converted to Swift (Swift 3):

```
    if let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField,
        let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar.leftView as? UIImageView {

            //Magnifying glass
            glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            glassIconView.tintColor = .whiteColor
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work now, I guess you have to supply your own image (in case use use UISeachController)

Comment: Worked for me still.

Answer (score 12):

This soultion worked for me on Xcode 8.2.1 in Swift 3.0. :

```
extension UISearchBar
{
    func setPlaceholderTextColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = color
        let textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
        textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel?.textColor = color
    }

    func setMagnifyingGlassColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as? UIImageView
        glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        glassIconView?.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
searchController.searchBar.setPlaceholderTextColorTo(color: mainColor)
searchController.searchBar.setMagnifyingGlassColorTo(color: mainColor)
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift-3:

```
extension UISearchBar
{

    func setMagnifyingGlassColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        // Search Icon
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as? UIImageView
        glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        glassIconView?.tintColor = color
    }

    func setClearButtonColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        // Clear Button
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let crossIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.value(forKey: "clearButton") as? UIButton
        crossIconView?.setImage(crossIconView?.currentImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        crossIconView?.tintColor = color
    }

    func setPlaceholderTextColorTo(color: UIColor)
    {
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = color
        let textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
        textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel?.textColor = color
    }
}
```

Call these extension method like this:

```
searchBarTextField.setMagnifyingGlassColorTo(color: yourColor)
searchBarTextField.setClearButtonColorTo(color: yourColor)
searchBarTextField.setPlaceholderTextColorTo(color: yourColor)
```

Answer (score 7):

For just changing the color of the search icon, without altering the actual icon in Swift 3:

```
if let textField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField,
    let iconView = textField.leftView as? UIImageView {

    iconView.image = iconView.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    iconView.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Creates a result like so:

[image: altered search bar icon]

Answer (score 6):

As per Federica's anwser....To do this in swift

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "search")!
self.searchBar.setImage(image, forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution for those using interface builder. You can add a User Defined Runtime Attribute to the UISearchBar:

`searchField.leftView.tintColor` of type `Color`
You can select the desired color of the icon, can be selected from your Color Assets library to support different colors for both light and dark mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 13, we now have access to many standard system icons via SF Symbols. Also, if you want to have a unified colour scheme for your search bars so that they all look the same without having to duplicate code, you can use the `Appearance` workflow to change them all at once. For example:

```
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(image, for: .search, state: .normal)
```

This code sets all search bars in the app to use the standard magnifying glass icon, in white. You can use similar code to change the 'clear' button icon, the bookmark icon and the results list icon. You just need to change `.search` to the appropriate enumeration value and find the system name of the appropriate icon (which you can get from the free SF System app).

Another method that uses `Appearance` would be to set the tint colour of all views contained within a search view, though this may have unwanted effects in some cases (i.e. changing the colour of the text cursor):

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = .yellow
```

This will make the left icon and the text cursor yellow, though annoyingly not the 'clear' button for some reason. I prefer not to use this method as it may not be future-proof; Apple has a habit of changing things internally that can cause unexpected changes if you don't use their approved methods.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from some of the answers here

If you would like to see and make the changes in storyboard first subclass UISearch bar and do as above.

However add the changes in a @IBInspectable variable and not forgetting the @IBDesignable at the top of the class and setting the searchbar subclass in the "Identity inspector"

I have added the full working subclass and code below for swift 3.0
Here you will be able to change the placeholder text, search text and magnifying glass

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {
@IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {

        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel = textFieldInsideSearchBar!.value(forKey: "placeholderLabel") as? UILabel
        textFieldInsideSearchBarLabel?.textColor = placeholderColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var textColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = textColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var magnifyingGlassColor: UIColor? {

    didSet {

        if let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField,
            let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar.leftView as? UIImageView {

            //Magnifying glass
            glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            glassIconView.tintColor = magnifyingGlassColor

        }        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you use the `setImage` API, pass an image with rendering mode of `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`. For example:

```
[self.searchBar setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed: @"icon-search"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are *no adequate reasons to set your own custom image* just for changing icon tint color. Don't forget about perfomance. And *retrieving a value by a raw string key doesn't garantee that other coders can mistype usually calling app crashes*. We're not perfect.

How about `UISearchBar` instance's property `searchTextField` ([`UISearchTextField`](https://google.com))?

```
if let thatMysteriousLoop = yourSearchBar.searchTextField.leftView as? UIImageView {
    thatMysteriousLoop.tintColor = anyColorYouWannaSet // <-- Voilà!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3

```
        searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "location-icon-black"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchBar.setTextColor(.white)
let textField = self.searchBar.getTextField()
let glassIconView = textField?.leftView as? UIImageView
glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
glassIconView?.tintColor = .white
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

extension UISearchBar {
    func getTextField() -> UITextField? {
        return self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    }

    func setTextColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        let textField = getTextField()
        textField?.textColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a proper way to set text color using `searchTextField`. Check: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/3175433-searchtextfield

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but since there is a Xamarin Bug on the dark mode and I was struggling for hours,  I thought I share my pretty easy solution.

iOS- custom Renderer.

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar),typeof(YourProjectSearchbarRenderer))]

```
public class YourProjectSearchbarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // iOS >13 -> Xamarin bug on darkmode,
            // just shows the light icon...
            this.Control.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(UIImage.FromFile("AddAnSearchIcon.ico"), UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(IOS_7) {
    self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    self.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] cornerRadius:5.0f];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.