# How to change icon color in SearchBar component Nativescript + Vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8DyP.jpg)

```
<SearchBar
    class="w-full rounded-full"
    textFieldHintColor="#fff"
    color="#fff"
    textProperty="#fff"
    backgroundImage="none"
    v-model="search"
    hint="Search..."
    @submit="fetchData"/>
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any API to change the Icon color currently, as it's styled by the styles.xml from App_Resources.

Android uses [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView), so you can style it like you'd do natively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57735080

iOS uses UISearchBar, which can also be styled natively: [How to change the color of the UISearchBar Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014529/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-uisearchbar-icon)

```
searchViewLoaded(event) {
  if(isAndroid) {
    const searchIcon event.object.android.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchIcon.setColorFilter(new Color('#ffffff').android, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
  } else {
    // UISearchBar
    event.object.ios.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = new Color('#ffffff').ios;
  }

}
```